# Wordpress check if any part of slug exists

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this code block below:

```
function the_slug_exists($post_name) {
    global $wpdb;
    if($wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = '" . $post_name . "'", 'ARRAY_A')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if (the_slug_exists($term)) :
    echo 'Ok';
endif;
```

Which seems to work fine. I want to altar the code to check if any part of the slug exists. For example the word "school" . I want to check all Wordpress pages to see if any page has the word "school" in it.

I do know Wordpress also has the function 'get_page_by_title' but I don't believe it will retrieve anything other than the exact title.

Answer (score 1):

change your SQL query to is LIKE instead of =

```
function the_slug_exists($post_name) {
    global $wpdb;
    if($wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name LIKE '%" . $post_name . "%'", 'ARRAY_A')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the function would I add something like this right before the if statement: $post_name = 'school';